# Center the strings in a popupmenu in Matlab's GUIDE or programmatically?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, popupmenu

I am looking to have all of the strings in a popupmenu centered in the menu. Now they are all left aligned and it just looks a little off.

Is there any way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the java handle to the uicontrol. You can get the java handle using [Yair's `findjobj` utility](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) from the file exchange.

```
p = uicontrol('style', 'popupmenu', 'String', {'item1', 'item2'}, 'Position', [0 0 200 30]);
jobj = findjobj(p);

renderer = jobj.getRenderer();
renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(renderer.CENTER);
```

[image]